# How can I specify org.openrewrite.java.logging.SystemPrintToLogging options?

Tags: java, openrewrite

I would very much appreciate a sample maven or YAML configuration for the four options this rewrite recipe supports, primarily `addLogger` and `logger` ... having been struggling with it for quite some time ...

```yaml
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: cleanup
displayName: "Cleanup"
description: "Cleanup"

recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.java.logging.SystemOutToLogging:
    loggerName: "logger"
    addLogger: "true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Before anybody looses their marbles and screams at YAML (again, again) ... all it took was extra spaces ...

```yaml
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: cleanup
displayName: "Cleanup"
description: "Cleanup"

recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.java.logging.SystemOutToLogging:
      loggerName: "logger"
      addLogger: "true"
```

Comment: Glad to see you worked it out! Know that you can easily configure, compose and export recipes through the builder at https://app.moderne.io/recipes/builder, from individual recipe pages such as https://app.moderne.io/recipes/org.openrewrite.java.logging.SystemOutToLogging